# how to get values from sql array, echo them by a defined variable

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to echo specific values from an selected SQL array, when they are equal to a defined variable.

Here's my defined variables:

```
$recipe1=1;
$recipe2=2;
$recipe3=3;
```

My SQL

```
$cat_sql = "
    SELECT feature_id, recipe_id, recipe_name, description, image
    FROM feature, recipes 
    WHERE recipe_id=$recipe[] ";
$result = mysql_query($cat_sql, $con);
$record = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Basically, I want something along the lines of:

```
<div> echo $recipe1_id; $recipe1_name; $recipe1_description</div>  
<div> echo $recipe2_id; $recipe2_name; $recipe2_description</div>
<div> echo $recipe3_id; $recipe3_name; $recipe3_description</div>
```

I want these values to be echo'd in different places (not part of an array) within  tags.

Comment: Read three times .. still can't figure out what you are after..

Comment: Can you double-check your question -- the "defined variables" part. Also your explanation of your goal isn't that clear.

Comment: when what is equal to what? :S

Comment: You have the same variable set to 3 different values (1,2,2). This will end up with value 2. Also in what you want to do, you are echoing the row regardless of the variable value?

Comment: have amended defined variables, thanks @azizSaleh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$result = mysql_query($cat_sql, $con);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    switch ($record['recipe_id']) {
        case $variable1:
            // do something
            break;
        case $variable2:
            // do something
            break;
        case $variable3:
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```

However, if you are going to print them regardless, then this should work:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $record['recipe_id'] . '-' . $record['recipe_name'] . '<br />';
}
```

To pick up certain rows

```
$select = array(1, 2, 3);
$cat_sql = "
SELECT feature_id, recipe_id, recipe_name, description, image
FROM feature, recipes 
WHERE recipe_id IN (" . implode(',', $select) . ")
";
```

Note: If this is new code, you should consider using PDO or MySQLI instead of MySQL.

Comment: will this fetch the different row values by the defined variable value?

Comment: The query will return all rows. If you want to return specific rows you will need to update the query (see above).

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. I'm looking for a query that will list values, from columns, when they are equal the defined variable.

Comment: @user3464091 That query I posted will do just that.

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks @AzizSaleh. But I don't want to echo the values in the same place as part of an array. Is there a way where I can echo the values in different places, for example within different <div>?